# How to show previous month's growth rate, that also takes care of year change and Jan-Dec in Power BI using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to calculate and show month on month growth rate in power bi, in both visual - Table and scorecard. In Table all the month should have their respective growth rate, except for current month (in some cases, otherwise can consider current month as well). And in scorecard if no month is selected from the slicer, current/previous month's growth rate should be visible. I had no issue before the year change.
Previously I used the following DAX to get the output:

```
MoM = VAR CurrentMonth = MONTH(TODAY())
VAR CurrentYear = YEAR(TODAY())
VAR LastYear = CurrentYear-1
VAR CurrentMonthPrice = CALCULATE([TotalPrice], FILTER(AllCommodities, AllCommodities[Year]=CurrentYear && MONTH(AllCommodities[Date])= CurrentMonth))
VAR LastYearMonthPrice = CALCULATE([TotalPrice], FILTER(AllCommodities, AllCommodities[Year]=LastYear && MONTH(AllCommodities[Date])= CurrentMonth))
VAR growth = DIVIDE(CurrentMonthPrice,LastYearMonthPrice)-enter image description here1
RETURN
IF(SELECTEDVALUE(AllCommodities[Commodities])="NA", "-", growth)
```

But due to year change, I'm unable to calculate the M-o-M rate. I tried using the following formula:

```
New MoM = 
DIVIDE(
    SUMX(FILTER(ALLSELECTED(trail), MONTH(trail[Date]) = MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW())) && YEAR(trail[Date]) = YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW()))), trail[Revenue]),
SUMX(FILTER(ALLSELECTED(trail), MONTH(trail[Date]) = IF(MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW()))=1,12,MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW()))-1) && YEAR(trail[Date]) = IF(MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW()))=1,YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW()))-1,YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW())))), trail[Revenue])) - 1
```

But it is only good for table visual and if a particular month is selected, it gives -100% error. which should not happen and give that particular month's growth rate.
How do I modify my DAX ?

Old DAX :

```
MoM = VAR CurrentMonth = MONTH(TODAY())
VAR CurrentYear = YEAR(TODAY())
VAR LastYear = CurrentYear-1
VAR CurrentMonthPrice = CALCULATE([TotalPrice], FILTER(AllCommodities, AllCommodities[Year]=CurrentYear && MONTH(AllCommodities[Date])= CurrentMonth))
VAR LastYearMonthPrice = CALCULATE([TotalPrice], FILTER(AllCommodities, AllCommodities[Year]=LastYear && MONTH(AllCommodities[Date])= CurrentMonth))
VAR growth = DIVIDE(CurrentMonthPrice,LastYearMonthPrice)-1
RETURN
IF(SELECTEDVALUE(AllCommodities[Commodities])="NA", "-", growth)
```

But it doesn't works for year change.

New DAX:
New MoM =
DIVIDE(
SUMX(FILTER(ALLSELECTED(trail), MONTH(trail[Date]) = MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW())) && YEAR(trail[Date]) = YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW()))), trail[Revenue]),
SUMX(FILTER(ALLSELECTED(trail), MONTH(trail[Date]) = IF(MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW()))=1,12,MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW()))-1) && YEAR(trail[Date]) = IF(MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW()))=1,YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW()))-1,YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(trail[Date],NOW())))), trail[Revenue])) - 1

```
But it doesn't work with scorecard or if a month is selected from the slicer , it gives -100% error.

[![Output required][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FIV3.png
```